# Magento 2 Admin Url or any other URL you are requesting not found on server 404

Tags: url-rewrite, magento2.4, 404, not-found, magento-admin

I tried all possible solutions on the internet but the still issue persists.

**Solutions that tried**

**1. ( Many solutions suggest changes in apache in following files ) /etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

Enabling apach2 rewrite mode first `a2enmod rewrite`
[image]

Changing from

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**to**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This sometimes works but in my case no luck

**2. Using /index.php/ after base URL for instance magento.com/index.php/admin**
[image]

In this case, few links were able to open but the admin was not opening

Comment: Have you got all the .htaccess files from the magento build?

Comment: Yes, brother the .htaccess file was from Magento build.

Comment: Note I said files. Many of the folders have specific .htaccess files and without them the css files won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue and it took me almost a day to resolve.
There are multiple solutions, I tried all possible solutions but there was no luck.

- Magento 2.1 Admin Url not found on the server
- Magento 2 - Localhost - Admin URL returning 404
- Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Many questions but one solution.
Simply at the root of your project add the .htaccess file and past this code and hopefully will work for you.

.htaccess code [.htaccess code need to be placed at the root of your project](https://github.com/hunzaigeek/MagentoFixes/blob/master/Magento%20fix.txt)

Comment: Make sure place this -> https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/.htaccess.sample at root of project